# Best practice for including source files from other projects

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to write the Makefile for a project, which depends on couple other projects (e.g. [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly)). To use some of the classes in folly, I include some header files from it in my code.

```
#include <folly/dynamic.h>
```

And folly also depends on another project called [double-conversion](https://code.google.com/p/double-conversion/). So what I do with Makefile is adding a flag for folly (-lfolly since I've already `make install` it) and `-I/path/to/folly/src/ -I/path/to/double-conversion/src/ -L/path/to/double-conversion/`.

```
g++ ... -lfolly ... -I/path/to/folly/src/ -I/path/to/double-conversion/src/ -L/path/to/double-conversion/
```

However, it would be quite a mess since I would like to distribute my project to other people and I don't want to have a super long instruction for them to hack all these paths in the Makefile. So I wonder if there are any other better practice for doing the same thing. Particularly, I don't think specifying all the absolute paths is the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn how to use a configure script or cmake.  These tools should automate the process to check on the dependencies of other libraries and will create an appropriate Makefile / build for the user's system based on their configurations.  When they run the scripts, the users will also be informed if they are missing any dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that's certainly a way to go, but I just wonder if there is a super simple way to go. For example, if I installed ```libevent``` and want to include some header files from ```libevent```, the only thing I need to do in my Makefile is to ```-levent```. Couldn't I do the same way in this scenario and what's the difference?

Comment: You need to indicate what library you are using (i.e. with -levent) and where to look for said libraries, i.e. a library path with the -L flag passed.  In order to make the header files included, you need to pass the -I flag to the compiler you are invoking.

Comment: Another option is in your Makefile is to create environment variables, like LIB_EVENT_PATH=/path/to/event, etc.

This way, you can have simple enough instructions for your users to 'hack' the Makefile by changing a couple variables in the Makefile.

Comment: That's a good idea. One thing I still don't understand is the difference between this scenario and ```libevent```. Why could I just do ```#include <event2/event.h>``` once ```libevent``` is installed, while I have to pointing out all the source files by ```-I``` in Makefile for ```folly```? In both case, I just did ```make && make install```.

Comment: Linking to a library provides the source / implementation, but does not give any info on the declaration of the functions in the library.  This is why you need the -I flags.

Comment: But why can I simply use ```#include <event2/event.h>``` in my code without having to specify ```-I/path/to/libevent/``` in Makefile then?

Comment: It depends on where the directory / file event2/event.h is located.  If it is in the default search directories, this is fine.  If not, then you must include it.  The issue becomes murky when you have users who will install libraries and headers in non-default locations (although, they will make sure that they are including these directories in their search paths).

Comment: i see, then what would be the default location for ```folly```'s source files, like ```/usr/local/include/folly```? and what about libraries?

Comment: If $SOMEPATH/folly is the main directory, then $SOMEPATH/folly/src/ contains the source *.cpp files, $SOMEPATH/folly/include/ contains the header *.h files, that you need to use the -I flag to point to, and the library will probably be installed in $SOMEPATH/folly/lib/